# How can i allow access to a specific url on my AWS Beanstalk site by certain ip

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a site hosted on AWS Beanstalk.
I need to allow all users to access https://my-web-page.com
But only allow certain ip addresses to access https://my-web-page.com/admin

Comment: What platform are you running? Limiting access to specific URLs will need to be done at the app server (nginx, apache, etc.) or application (php, rails, node, etc.) level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a [ebextension](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html) script(s) to modify the configuration of the proxy that's sitting in front your app server.

```
container_commands:
  replace_httpd_conf:
    command: cp .ebextensions/httpd.conf /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

You're going to have either httpd and nginx sitting in front depending on what app server you're using.  Tomcat and Django both have httpd,  I believe node uses nginx.  Not sure about the others.

Here's the page on access restriction for [httpd](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html) 2.2.  You config would look something like

```
<Location /admin>
    Require ip 1.1.1.1
</Location>
```